# Where is the Image Magick Source Folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, imagemagick

I need to uninstall Image Magick for the 100th time because I am missing delegate libraries. Where is the Source folder found so that I can "make uninstall" it? Is there is a default location? Running a search for ImageMagick returns nothing but the binary folders. If I have deleted the folder in the past, what are some options for uninstalling and then reinstalling? FYI I built it from source, not from apt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ImageMagick is installed, try running:

```
magick -list configure     # new v7 syntax
identify -list configure   # old v6 syntax
```

to see where/how it was built. There is no real need to uninstall, just install again after installing all delegates.

---

By the way, the **Alpine Linux** version of **ImageMagick** comes with just about every delegate installed, so if you have **docker**, you can run:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine:latest
```

Inside **docker**, simply run:

```
apk add --no-cache imagemagick
```

and you'll have all this:

```
magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-57 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-10 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jpeg lcms ltdl lzma png ps rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib
```

Comment: Thank you, knowing you don't need to uninstall just to reinstall is very helpful to know!